# c# BeginReceive callback

Tags: c#, asyncsocket

I'm building a program which will communicate with sockets. I've a question about this, I'm using async sockets and I do

```
socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), State);
```

to start listening that socket I also add this socket to my socket list to send data to all my connected clients my question here is inside my ReceiveCallBack I want to do a few works which can take up to 1000-1500 ms but I wonder if this situation will block anything else, because I dont want to lose any incoming data while I process previous data. I was thinking of adding the incoming data to a list and then do my work there but I'm not either sure if this is the right way to go because I will use

```
while(true)
```

and use list.FirstOrDefault() and then just remove it at the end of my work..

Can someone show me the correct way if possible please?

Comment: Just to be clear, you will not lose any data by doing long processing in your callback, though transmission speed will be slower than without it. If your processing is really, really slow your connection may time out, but those timeouts are fairly long by default and can be set manually to be even longer.

Comment: The problem while continues receiving is that if the processing is slower, you'll get a memory problem. If that is probably not the case, you can store it in a list and process it on another thread.

Comment: One thing you can do is to shift your long running processing on separate thread instead on executing it on the receive call back thread. This way you can achieve responsiveness. But make sure to manage memory at your own because you will be consuming un-managed memory during the transportation of data.

Comment: I cant handle every request in another threads because the order of data is important to me, sometimes the incoming data might store over 1000 list items(JSON Objects) and I am actually dividing the data to 20 so I can process each list item and give answer to my clients. Since doing all the 1000 work takes over 2-3 min I want to inform the clients time to time about whats going on in server. So I decide to use a big list and a small one, big one is dividing to 20 and sending to small(process) list and small one is doing the work and send answer..

Comment: If you store the received messages on a list and process that list with a dedicated thread. The order isn't affected. The dedicated thread can send updates to clients whenever it needs to. This way your receiving/processing is separated.

Comment: @J.vanLangen is absolutely right. Simply pass that list to separate thread and process in way you want. Order will not be impacted.

Comment: Okay so in my ReceiveCallBack I'll just simply add the incoming data and process the whole list in another thread, right?

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: Okay thank you, I'll do it